# saving fragment state actionbar tab

Tags: android, tabs, fragment, android-actionbar

I am building an app that consists of actionbar with tabs, and each tab consists of a fragment. One of the fragments has data that need to be loaded. So I want the data to be loaded only the first time. When the user changes the tabs and goes back to the one containing that fragment, doesn't wait for the data to be loaded again. I assume I have to use some kind of saving the data so that it can be used the next time the user goes back to that particular fragment. But I just do not know what method I should use. If someone knows or can suggest an example of saving fragment state, please let me know. Thank u!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
myFragment.setRetainInstance(true);
```

It'll mean the fragment isn't recreated every time it's added.

Comment: I've tried that, but does not do the work. When i go to other tabs and come back to that particular tab, onCreate is called again. I assume that shouldn't be happening.

Comment: It looks like your are forcibly re-creating the Fragment. You need to use the same object.

Comment: Yes, I've realized that just now. I solved the problem by changing some things in the onTabSelected and onTabUnselected functions from the TabListener. When the user clicks on a different tab I HIDE the fragment that I want to be loaded only the first time, rather than removing it. So, the next time that the user clicks on that particular fragment I only show it. Thank u for your reply anyway.

Comment: @OllieC I am having the same issue. Where would I add `myFragment.setRetainInstance(true);`

Comment: @Sandra What did you end up doing to fix the issue?

Comment: You have my answer in the comment above. I hide the fragment of interest (the one that I don't want to be created again), so clicking back on that tab, I simply show it. Use the methods of the tab listener.